# Opensource CMS site with points, profile page and approval

Tags: php, asp.net, jsp, content-management-system

What Opensource CMS frameworks in any language (PHP,.net,java) are there, wherein the users are the contributors to the site? The users can submit articles which will then be reviewed by an admin for publishing. The writers will also have there own profile page and reputation points.

Examples:

1. Think of it as Stackoverflow but for articles and your posts has to
   be approved by an admin first.
2. [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com)

Comment: Pretty much any modern CMS has such features, or the ability to add them as a plugin.

Comment: Don't know but I bet Wordpress has a plugin for the extra part (reputation points), the rest is almost a common feature in the main CMSs around (either native or with popular plugins). Alternatively, try Joomla! and its extensions base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) with little bit customizations.